# "X is part of the declarations of 2 modules" creating shared module

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I got the following component modal.bed.ts, this component is imported in 2 different tabs inside my application. However, that is not allowed. So I figured out that I need to create a shared module, but now I'm stuck.

This is modal.bed.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
    template: `<ion-header>Bed</ion-header>`,
    selector: 'page-modal'
})

export class ModalPageBedComponent {

    constructor(private ctrl: ModalController) { }

    async close() {
        this.ctrl.dismiss();
    }
}
```

I then Import in inside my tab2.module.ts as followed

```
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';    
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { Tab3Page } from './tab2.page';

import { ModalPageBedComponent } from '../modal/modal.bed';
    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        IonicModule,
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
          RouterModule.forChild([{ path: '', component: Tab3Page }]),
          RouterModule.forChild([{ path: '', component: ModalPageBedComponent}]),
      ],
      declarations: [
          Tab2Page,
          ModalPageBedComponent,
      ]
    })
    export class Tab2PageModule {}
```

The import is the same for tab3.module.ts, but then it's Tab3 instead of Tab2.

Then In my tab2.page.ts I import it as well by doing

```
import {ModalPageBedComponent} from '../modal/modal.bed';
```

then I can use it inside my page by doing:

async presentModal(obj) {

```
let cmp = null;
alert(obj)

// Selects the object's class
switch (obj) {
    case 'Bed'.toString(): {
        cmp = ModalPageBedComponent;
        break;
    }
.....
```

I'm using it the same way in tab3.page.ts. So now I need to create a shared module, that imports and exports the components because a component cannot be declared twice.

So I created the following modal.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { ModalPageBedComponent } from '../modal/modal.bed';
import { ModalPageTvComponent } from '../modal/modal.tv';
import { ModalPageLampComponent } from '../modal/modal.lamp';
import { ModalPageFridgeComponent } from '../modal/modal.fridge';
import { ModalPageFanComponent } from '../modal/modal.fan';
import { ModalPageWindowComponent } from '../modal/modal.window';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
    ],
    declarations: [
        ModalPageBedComponent,
        ModalPageFanComponent,
        ModalPageFridgeComponent,
        ModalPageLampComponent,
        ModalPageTvComponent,
        ModalPageWindowComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        ModalPageBedComponent,
        ModalPageFanComponent,
        ModalPageFridgeComponent,
        ModalPageLampComponent,
        ModalPageTvComponent,
        ModalPageWindowComponent
    ]
})

export class SharedModalModule {}
```

Now I tried importing SharedModalModule inside my tab2.page.ts.

```
import {SharedModalModule} from '../modal/modal.module';
```

However, I can't figure out how to access the ModalPageBedComponent. I'm not sure if I'm doing it right, I searched and read multiple articles about it. But I don't quite follow how I'm now supposed to access ModalPageBedComponent inside my tab2.page.ts by only importing SharedModalModule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understand is that you've created a sharedModule to import and export the components you're going to repeat, right? so you need to import the SharedModule in the Module when you're declaring the "father"s component when the other components are going to be called. I'll try to explain:

You have this module somewhere (I'm going to assume it's the main module)

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ModulesModule } from './modules/modules.module';
import { SharedModalModule } from './shared/shared.modal.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    //.. and whatever components you have here
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    SharedModalModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

There, you import your ShareModule so the components declared here are going to be able to use the components declared and exported in that SharedModule you've created.

I hope I understood correctly your question and I hope it helps.